# How can I pass a function's return value as another function's argument?

Tags: c++, function

How can I use the first function's return value as the second function's parameter/argument?

Once that's done, how do call these two functions in main()?

Thanks for the help.

```
#include <iostream>

//function 1 - returns a string
std::string userinput()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a word: ";
    std::string word{};
    std::cin >> word;
    return word;
}

//function 2 - should accept the return value of function 1, print its length
int inputlength()
{
    std::cout << "There are " << word.length() << "letters in this word";
    return 0;
}

//how would I run the function calls in main?????
int main()
{
    //function calls
}
```

Comment: You might want to get the code for the functions working, before worrying about passing the return value from one to the other.   The second function (`inputlength()`) would not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding the parameter(s) between the  `()`

eg.

```
int inputlength(const std::string& word) {
```

Using a const reference here. `&` means it is a reference and `const` meaning the string object is constant (cannot be modified inside the function).

Another way would be:

```
int inputlength(std::string word) {
```

It would mean: *take a copy of the string*

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

//function 1 - returns a string
std::string userinput()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a word: ";
    std::string word{};
    std::cin >> word;
    return word;
}

//function 2 - should accept the return value of function 1, print its length
int inputlength()
{
    std::cout << "There are " << word.length() << "letters in this word";
    return 0;
}

//how would I run the function calls in main?????
int main()
{
    std::cout<<inputlength(userinput())<<std::endl;
}
```